# Sencha touch remove group header and increase gap

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I remove Sencha touch grouped list header and increase the gap.

Comment: I want to remove the grouped list headers. and if possible increase the gap between the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom class for your list and add the css for that class in your css file.
Off-course, with grouped config options set to true if u r using a store and add desired fieldname to be grouped.

**View:**

```
Ext.define('app.view.Temp', {
        extend : 'Ext.List',
        xtype : 'temp',

        config : {
            title : 'Temp',
            cls : 'x-contacts',
            disableSelection: true,
            grouped : true,
            store : 'YourStore',
            ui : 'round',
            cls:'modifiedHeader',
            //custom css classname
            itemTpl : ['<span>{field_name}</span>'].join('')
        }
    });
```

---

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('app.store.YourStore', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

        config : {
            model : 'app.model.Temp',
            autoLoad : true,
            storeId:'YourStore',
             groupField: 'field_name',

            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                url : 'link/to/api'
            }
        }
    });
```

---

**app.css**

```
.modifiedHeader .x-list-header {
//your desired css here
display:none;//If you want to hide the header
}
```